# Prove that, “If RST is the triangle in Exercise $2.23$, then triangle SUR is congruent to triangle SUT.”

Tags: logic, proof-verification

Prove that, “If RST is the triangle in Exercise $2.23$, then triangle SUR is congruent to triangle SUT.”

I would greatly appreciate it if any of the gracious mathematicians on MSE could take the time to review my reasoning to ensure that it is correct. If there are any errors, please specify why it is an error and what the correct reasoning should be. You all have my gratitude.

I have drawn the triangle in question:

[image]

In proving the statement I have used the forwards and backwards methods. **A** represents the hypothesis, and **B** represents the conclusion.

**Proof:**

**A:** $\overline{RU} = \overline{UT}$

**B:** $SUR = SUT$

**A1:** $\angle SUR = \angle SUT = 90 ^\circ$

**A2:** $\overline{SU} = \overline{SU}$

How can I show that two right triangles are congruent?

Two right triangles are congruent if the hypotenuse and one leg of one right triangle is equal to the hypotenuse and one leg of the other right triangle.

**B1:** $\overline{RS} = \overline{ST} \land \ \overline{SU} = \overline{SU}$ *Please note that I have chosen to use the leg $\overline{SU}$, since it is mentioned previously in **A2**.*

How can I show that the hypotenuses of two right triangles are equal?

Use the perpendicular bisector theorem to show that if a point is on the perpendicular bisector of a segment then it is equidistant from the endpoint of the segment.

**B2:** $\overline{RS} = \overline{ST}$ *This statement is not saying that this is true; It is saying that if this is true then the conclusion **B** is true.

**A3:** $\overline{RS} = \overline{ST}$ Q.E.D *It can be seen that $\overline{SU}$ is the perpendicular bisector, and $S$ is a point on the perpendicular bisector. Therefore, $S$ is equidistant from the endpoints $R$ and $T$. This proves that the hypotenuses of both right triangles are equal.*

Comment: could you please put the original problem? It is very confusing. I can't understand what you want.

Comment: @ArnaldoNascimento The original problem is as written at the top of the OP. Are you referring to exercise 2.23? That exercise is not relevant to this problem; only the triangle diagram (as drawn) is relevant. Is there anything you would like me to clarify?

Comment: you already solved the problem. You did $RU=UT$, $\angle SUR = \angle SUT$ and $SU=SU$. That is enough to conclude that $\Delta RUS \equiv \Delta TUS$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already solved the problem.

You have $RU=UT$, $∠SUR=∠SUT$ and $SU=SU$.

That is the case (side, angle, side) for congruence of triangle. In particular, it holds for a right triangle.

That is enough to conclude that $ΔRUS≡ΔTUS$.

Comment: This is the angle-side-angle theorem of triangle congruence? I didn't even notice. If we ignore this is my reasoning still correct?

Comment: check again the answer. Is that clear?

Comment: Indeed, it is clear. I believe this is the angle-side-angle (ASA) theorem of triangle congruence. But if we ignore this is my other (full) reasoning still correct?

Comment: that is not $(ASA)$, it is $(SAS)$.

Comment: You're correct; I got them confused.